# Where should I place common code when writing angular directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm in a situation where I would like to have many directives with different
tag names, but which are nearly identical in their behaviour. My first idea
was to just capture the directive as a function like this:

```
function standardDirective(template,extract) {
  return function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      ... }
     }
  }
```

and then use this function to 'stamp out' the required directives.

```
angular.module('MCQ', [])
  .directive('mcq' 
            , standardDirective("MCQTemplate.html"
                               , function(scope){return scope.userSelection;}
                               )
            );
```

After writing this, I'm pretty sure that there is some common, and possibly better
idiom, for doing this. For example, in my 'solution' I probably can't make angular load the `standardDirective` when it is needed.

(I know that I could make a single directive and use attributes to differentiate behaviour, but for now, let's assume that I really need different directives..)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `require` option on the directive.

This essentially ensures that your directive "inherits" another directive, like a base class.

Your 'base' directive can contain all of your common logic and then then other directive that is `requiring` it has it's own spin on whatever it needs to do.

you can read more about it [in the Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) - see the Creating Directives that Communicate section